# Проблема при запуске Андроид Студио

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При запуске Андроид Студио появляется следующая запись:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't create Engine
at com.google.android.filament.Engine.create(Engine.java:46)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.viewer.Filamentor$3.run(Filamentor.java:103)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже есть решение на github, в самом низу есть коментарий с обьяснением.

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/411